# How to prevent conditioned command evaluation in Ansible's shell provisioning?

Tags: python, ruby, ansible, vagrant, virtualbox

I've got the following multi-machine Vagrant setup:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "xfcevm" do |xfcevm|
    xfcevm.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1904"
    xfcevm.vm.hostname = "xfcevm"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "ubuntu-xfce"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "kdevm" do |kdevm|
    kdevm.vm.box = "generic/arch"
    kdevm.vm.hostname = "kdevm"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "arch-kde"
    end
  end

  ## only Arch doesn't ship with Python installed
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "which python || sudo pacman --noconfirm -S python"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "32"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
    ansible.playbook = "setup.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"
  end

end
```

As Arch vagrant box doesn't include Python, so I've created an inline shell provision command that should test for the existence of Python (by `which python`) and if that evaluates to false then the `pacman` installation of Python should follow. For echoing output the second part shouldn't be evaluated and that's the case by running the command in terminal.

But shell provisioner evaluates the part after `||` anyway, no matter if Python exists. In the case of Ubuntu, it raises an obvious error for `pacman` not being installed:

```
$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'xfcevm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'kdevm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> xfcevm: Checking if box 'generic/ubuntu1904' version '1.9.34' is up to date...
==> xfcevm: Running provisioner: shell...
    xfcevm: Running: inline script
    xfcevm: sudo
    xfcevm: : 
    xfcevm: pacman: command not found
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Also the same goes with a simple if statement instead of `||`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "if [ ! `which python` ]; then sudo pacman --noconfirm -S python; fi"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Also, I do not see anywhere in your output the path that `which` has found for your tool. So I strongly suspect that, depending on the user you connect with, `which` is not finding your python install, resulting in your second command running.

Comment: I've figured it out and have provided an answer. Tnx for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is a combination of two things: using python as an alias to Python3 in Arch (as contrary to Ubuntu where python is an alias for Python2) and the fact that Ubuntu doesn't ship with Python2 (and we don't need it for Ansible purposes, we use Python3).

So the solution is to check for both `python` and `python3`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "if [ ! `which python`] && [ ! `which python3` ]; then sudo pacman --noconfirm -S python; fi"
```

Answer (score 1):

After a test on my machine with the following Vagranfile:

```rb
 Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
     config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1904"
     config.vm.hostname = "test"
     config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
     config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
     config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
         v.memory = 2048
         v.cpus = 2
     end
     config.vm.provision "default", type: "shell", inline: "which python", run: "always"
 end
```

this is the result of `vagrant up` (only last lines)

```
==> default: Running provisioner: default (shell)...
    default: Running: inline script
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Checking interactively:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Wed Oct  9 15:33:22 2019 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@test:~$ which python
vagrant@test:~$ echo $?
1
vagrant@test:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
vagrant@test:~$ echo $?
0
vagrant@test:~$
```

Conclusion: what you get is totally coherent. `python` does not exists in your ubuntu image so the rest of your command is run. Your scenario has a flaw and you need to find an other way.

In your context, I would try to run everything in ansible. Here is an example just for the idea, that I didn't test and that can surely be greatly improved

```
- name: Make sure machine can run ansible
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Try to ansible-ping the host. Consider python is not installed otherwise
          ping:

      rescue:
        - name: No python available, install with low-level and dirty command
          become: true
          become_method: sudo
          raw: pacman --noconfirm -S python
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I provided the answer before seeing your answer. Yep, the problem is Ubuntu and Arch different `python` alias meaning. I've solved it with a double `||`. Dunno for the ansible solution version, maybe if in the future current solution can't longer fit. Thanks!